# Safe Updates no PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

No MySQL Workbench tem uma função muito útil chamada: "Safe Updates", que impede Updates em uma coluna sem WHERE, por exemplo.

No PHPMyAdmin, existe esta função? Não consegui encontrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções:

- remover do usuario que acessa o PHPMyAdmin a permissao de DELETE e UPDATE e criar uma stored procedure para essa operaçoes (que exige entre seus parametros, o conteudo da clausula WHERE)
- você pode criar triggers que dao ROLLBACK no upda te se o numero de linhas atualizadas for igual ao numero de linhas da tabela (pode dar errado se outros usuarios inserirem registros em paralelo)
- você pode customizar o codigo do PHP MyAdmin (que é aberto) para que ele valide o conteudo dos formularios de query e impeça o usuario de submeter UPDATEs e DELETEs sem where, claro que, pra fazer isso, você precisa conhecer o codigo do PHPMyAdmin e precisa ser capaz de incluir tal alteração sem dar pau no restante das funcionalidades

Comment: Ótimo, Marcelo Bezerra! Muito obrigado!